# Is there a way to point a sub-directory of a web role deployment to an Azure web site?

Tags: iis, azure

I would like to be able to have my ASP.NET web application run on a web role for scalability and have a subdirectory point to an Azure website. Like this:

http://www.mysite.com -> resolves to my web role deployment.

http://www.mysite.com/blog -> resolves to a WordPress website deployed on Azure.

I know on a virtual machine I could do this by installing WordPress and pointing a virtual directory under my main site to the location of the WordPress application. I am familiar with the ability to use the ARR web farms and URL Rewriting to accomplish something similar in IIS, but can this be done from within an Azure web role? Is there an easier way? (like by using some really sweet Azure URL rewriting tool)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MVC, register a route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Blog",
    url: "blog",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Blog" }
);
```

and have the controller/action redirect:

```
public ActionResult Blog()
{
    return Redirect("http://blog.com")
}
```

If you are using webforms, map the route to a redirect aspx page, and in the Page_Load, redirect.

Finally, you could use URL Rewrite by including something like below in your web.config:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Blog">
            <match url="^.*/blog.*" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="http://blog.com" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: I cannot have the redirect, because I don't want the URL to change after the response. Does rewriting to another site actually work? I thought you needed ARR web farm to do that. I will give it a try, but I have to learn how to install stuff in IIS on Azure web role first.

Comment: If you have a web role, you can RDP into the instance and install to IIS, but the install will not survive a role update.  You can add install tasks via powershell, but this is a bit complicated.  I think you are fighting a huge uphill battle.  The only way I know to keep the same URL (as a sub-directory) is to iframe the blog into a page on the parent site - a terrible option.